# Django signals получить id поля с foreign key

Tags: django

имеется форма которая добавляет данные к БД и в ней есть поле foreign key связанное с другой таблицей. Необходимо брать id значения этого поля и при изменении или создании данных в этой форме, обновлять данные в таблице, к которой привязан этот foreign key.

Используя сигналы, все что мне удалось извлечь из этой формы при создании или редактировании это имя, которое в модели определено как **str**. Как взять id пока не могу понять. Остальное, как обновить данные в другой таблице знаю, нужно только взять нужный элемент по id.

Comment: Приложите код, так очень сложно понять, что вы делаете

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно зачем нужно использовать сигналы. Если есть форма при сохранении(добавление, редактирование) которой нужно что-то менять.
То просто переопредели метод `save` этой формы таким образом, что бы он вносил все требуемые изменения.